# Hide specific ListView cells onTouch in android

Tags: android, listview

I am in grave need of an effect with something like this

[image: Before Touch]

[image: On Touch]

See how the listview collapses the touched item's child? How can I achieve this effect?

I am able to drag and drop list items. My listview is backed by a custom adapter that extends a cursor adapter. Can I achieve this effect in my BindView method? How will it be possible?(I will need the current position and the view that's being touched ) My listview is basically from this library :
https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

The screenshots are from gtasks app

Thanks

Regards 
Parvaz Bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by changing the cursor of the adapter whenever the item is selected.
In my onclick method I re-queried the database and changed a column value for those I wanted to hide . Then Created a new cursor, omitting those columns that I don't need , and changed the cursor with the new one.

hope this helps someone.

Regards,
Parvaz Bhaskar